# Prepared Statement effect against SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

For example, I have the code below:

```
import java.sql.*; ...
public void main (string[] args){ 
try {
 Class.forName („COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Driver“);} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {//error handling}
try {
    String url = "jdbc:db2://host:6789/myDB2"
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "login", "password");
    PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE PERS SET Salary=Salary*2.0 WHERE PNR=?"

    pStmt.setInt (1, 35);
    pStmt.executeUpdate();

    pStmt.setString (1, args[0]); 
    pStmt.executeUpdate();

    con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { //error handling}
}
```

Presumably we have the table like:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
|PNR     |Name      |Salary     |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|34      |Tim       |20000      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|35      |John      |45000      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

I have a difficult time predicting what will happen if:

```
args[0]="35 OR Salary<100000"
```

Doesn't the `setString` command replace `args[0]` with `35 OR Salary < 100000` and then all the salary record gets doubled?

Answer (score 2):

That won't cause SQL injection issues. It will translate to:

```
UPDATE PERS SET Salary=Salary*2.0 WHERE PNR='35 OR Salary<100000'
```

The inserted quotes will save you from SQL injection. I am simplifying a bit. JDBC implementation determines how exactly `PreparedStatement` translates to a real SQL query. It doesn't necessarily actually translate it to the above SQL. But this is one way it can prevent attacks.

Careful, though. If you use user input to create your SQL, you sill still be susceptible to SQL injection. As long as you use user inputs only to call `.setXYZ()` params, you'll be safe from it.

Comment: Are you saying that prepared statements actually build the resulting SQL statement as string internally?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Could you also tell me what the number "1" in `pstmt.setInt(1, 35)` means? Does it mean the first entry?

Comment: @lexicore Not necessarily. What PreparedStatement does internally depends on the specific JDBC implementation. But this is the rough idea of how it can prevent issues.

Comment: @noobcoder The `1` refers to the parameter index. Here, we are saying that "replace the first param"

Answer (score 2):

## Server-Side Prepared Statements

SQL parameters help to avoid SQL injection because the value of the parameter is not combined with the SQL query at all. The SQL query with parameter placeholders is sent to the MySQL server, where it is parsed and analyzed. It does things like check that you wrote valid SQL syntax, that the tables and columns you reference exist, and you have the right privileges to access those tables and columns.

This is why parameters can't be used for table names or column names or other syntax. Because the validation occurs when the parameters are still left as placeholders. The value of the parameters is sent later, so the validation must assume a parameter must replace only a single scalar value in your SQL query.

After this point, the query is stored internally in the MySQL server as non-textual data structures. It is no longer in SQL, it's just a number of internal objects in the MySQL code. The places where you had used `?` become query elements that MySQL knows need to be supplied with values before it can execute the query.

When you run `pStmt.executeUpdate()` the values of the variables you bound to the parameters are sent to the MySQL server. They are filled into the placeholders in the non-textual representation of the query.

This way, the parameter values are not combined until after the parsing is done, therefore there's no way for the content of the parameter to change the SQL syntax. It affects the SQL query only like a single string would, as if there were a type of quote delimiter that could not be broken by unmatched quote characters in the parameter content.

Query parameters are a reliable way to protect against SQL injection.

## Emulated Prepared Statements

Some drivers implement an "emulated" prepared statement. This means it does nothing with the SQL query you pass to `prepareStatement()`, except save the SQL string in the JDBC driver (on the client-side). It does not send the SQL query to the server at this time.

Then when you run `executeUpdate()` your variables are interpolated into the parameter placeholders in the SQL string, and the full string is sent to the server. Then the MySQL server parses the combined SQL query, with parameter values and all. MySQL Server can't even tell which values were literal values in the original SQL query versus which were combined as parameters. They all appear as literal values to the parser.

In this case, you have to trust that the JDBC driver does correct escaping, so quotes and other characters inside your parameter content can't mix up the SQL parser. The driver should be well-tested to handle all cases, like special character sets, and hex-encoded quote characters and other ways to trick it.

Comment: Isn't the question about DB2, not MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, I answer a lot of MySQL questions. I have removed the info about the MySQL JDBC driver. I don't know which type of prepared statement the DB2 JDBC driver supports, I assume it's server-side. All the rest of my content is relevant to any brand of SQL database.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, have you ever encountered a JDBC driver that implements an `emulated prepared statement`? If the programmer is unaware of this, it could potentially pose a security risk (beacuse s(he) might fail to do proper input sanitation etc).

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver supports emulated prepare, because MySQL prior to 2004 didn't support server-side prepared statements. By default, the MySQL driver does use server-side prepared statements. It's not a security risk if the driver implements escaping correctly.